# How to center a value in a tree graph

Tags: tikz-trees

I'm trying to center a value in one probability graph  tree, but i can't. Can anyone help me?
This is the code that i'm running and this is the output.I'm trying to center the value 56.444, but with no result.

[image: Output]

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[grow=right, sloped]
\node[bag] {40}

child {
    node[bag] {33.484}        
        child {
            node[end, label=right:
                {28.029}] {}
            edge from parent
            node[above] {}
            node[below]  {}
        }
        child {
            node[end, label=right:
                {39.775}] {}
            edge from parent
            node[above] {}
            node[below]  {}
        }
        edge from parent 
        node[above] {}
        node[below]  {}
}
child {
    node[bag] {47.516}        
    child {
            node[end, label=right:
                {39.775}] {}                
        }
        child {
            node[bag, label=-45:
                {56.444}] {}
             child {
            node[end, label=right:
                {56.444}] {}
            edge from parent
            node[above] {}
            node[below]  {}
        }     child {
            node[end, label=right:
                {56.444}] {}
            edge from parent
            node[above] {}
            node[below]  {}
        }   } 
            };
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Why are you using a label? Just put the value as the text of the node (between `{` and `}`).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was literally stack!

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative, you might consider using `forest`, which makes the code much simpler:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={grow'=east,
    if n children=0{edge=-{Circle[length=2pt]}, child anchor=west}{},
    l sep=1.2cm, s sep=5mm
}
[40
  [47.516
    [56.444
      [56.444][56.444]
    ]
    [39.775]
  ]
  [33.484
    [39.775][28.029]
  ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```